# .Net interface with AutoCad - how to make a selection

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

How to select all object within the drawing?

Sometthing related to

```
AcadSelectionSet select = _acadCurrentDocument.SelectionSets.Add("my");
select.Select(AcSelect.acSelectionSetAll);
```

But cannot make it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In real .NET AutoCAD API (in process, not C#/COM like in your exemple):

```
Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
Database db = doc.Database;
Editor ed = doc.Editor;
PromptSelectionResult psr = ed.GetSelection();
if (psr.Status != PromptStatus.OK) return;
using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
    foreach (SelectedObject so in psr.Value)
    {
        var dbo = tr.GetObject(so.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForRead);
        //...
    }
    tr.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to do the selection in a standalone executable, the AutoCAD COM Interop is the way to go as you were trying. You may need to if the AutoCAD has been open or not and if it's the version you like.

You may need to activate the AutoCAD window too if necessary.